# How to identify camera that is for IR depth only (e.g. Pixel 4's Face Unlock camera)?

Tags: android, android-camera2, infrared

Newer phones have multiple front-facing cameras (e.g. Pixel 4 has one for normal RGB image, another for face unlock based on IR)

I would like to respond to them differently, but [`CameraCharacteristics`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics) does not seem to have an attribute that fits this need.  I tried [`DEPTH_DEPTH_IS_EXCLUSIVE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#DEPTH_DEPTH_IS_EXCLUSIVE), [`STATISTICS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FACE_DETECT_MODES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#STATISTICS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FACE_DETECT_MODES).  Neither seems to be able to specifically tell me a camera is *only* for IR depth use only.

Any hints?

Comment: Perhaps you should worry about what you *need*, rather than the specific official purpose, ie, color and a reasonable resolution, and pick the one with the best properties or allow choosing in order of decreasing capability.

Comment: A little context:  My app listens to camera availability events to display an arrow pointing to where the camera is (depending on the make/model) to help people look straight at the camera...  It works if there are only one front-facing camera (only for RGB images).  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evergreenlabs.selfiecamarrow